# Numpy: Fill matrix containing NaN's with minimum value from rows in the matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Given a matrix

```
matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,np.nan,3],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]])
```

Get a vector containing the minimum value for each row

```
vector_of_min_row_values = np.nanmin(matrix, axis=1)
```

How do you replace the NaN values in each row with the min values of the row. This should create a matrix like this:

```
output_matrix = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,1,3],[np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `numpy.where` and reshaping of the `numpy.nanmin` output:

```
output_matrix = np.where(np.isnan(matrix), np.nanmin(matrix, 1)[:,None], matrix)
```

output:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  3.],
       [nan, nan, nan]])
```